# #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.sender_id:

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm building three models in my rails application. One model references the same model twice as shown in my [DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhRmZ.png). The only problem is that when I make a POST Request to create a new record in my shipment table. I get this error:

```js
#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.sender_id: SELECT  \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"sender_id\" = ? LIMIT ?>
```

I don't think that I need to add a sender_id & receiver_id column in my users table because the sender_id & receiver_id are basically the User_ID in the users column. Any help would be much appreciated it!

This is my user.rb file:

```js
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :shipments 
end
```

This is my shipment.rb

```html
class Shipment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", primary_key: "sender_id"
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User", primary_key: "receiver_id"

  validates_uniqueness_of :tntcode
end
```

This is my shipments_controller:

```html
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController

    def index 
        shipments = Shipment.all
    end 

    def show
        shipment = Shipment.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def create
        shipment = Shipment.new(shipment_params)
      
        if shipment.save
          render json: {status: 'Shipment created successfully'}, status: :created
        else
          render json: { errors: shipment.errors.full_messages }, status: :bad_request
        end
    end 
    
    def shipment_params
        params.require(:shipment).permit(:tntcode, :status, :shipment_type, :weight, :content, :price, :sender_id, :receiver_id)
    end
end
```

And my schema.rb:

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180826123320) do

  create_table "shipments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "tntcode"
    t.string "status"
    t.string "shipment_type"
    t.integer "weight"
    t.string "content"
    t.integer "price"
    t.integer "sender_id"
    t.integer "receiver_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["receiver_id"], name: "index_shipments_on_receiver_id"
    t.index ["sender_id"], name: "index_shipments_on_sender_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email", null: false
    t.string "role"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "photourl"
    t.string "userid"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change the `primary_key` on your `belongs_to` associations: that's the other table's ID column (`id`).

You instead want:

```
belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id"
belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "receiver_id"
```

... which is the default, so this should work too:

```
belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User"
```